# For the Window's version of Ubuntu, how do we find the password?

Tags: windows, password, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've recently installed Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store page. I works fine but then I get to a problem.
When I tried to update my packages with `sudo apt update`, it prompted me for the password.

I have logged into this device with a fingerprint, and have a PIN for backup.

...what on earth is the password then?

I've tried entering the PIN, *no luck*, just a return for empty password, *still no luck*, and now I'm at my wit's end.

Please send help.

Answer (score 0):

Log into Ubuntu and run id :

```
$ id
uid=1000(midway) gid=985(users) groups=985(users),98(power),988(storage),998(wheel)
```

In my case, midway is my username. Get your username from your install.

Now logout of ubuntu and into normal windows `cmd.exe`. Run `ubuntu.exe` like below :

```
ubuntu config --default-user root
```

The prompt will change and you will be logged into ubuntu as root. Now run the following  from within the ubuntu root prompt.

```
passwd <userNameYouObtainedFromAbove>
```

This command will set the password for ubuntu's default user. Follow the prompts. Once done, exit out of ubuntu root session and start a new Ubuntu session as you normally do.

You can now use this newly set password to run your `apt install`